# Problems with comparing class methods

Tags: c++

I need help comparing values of a class, but the bool methods isn't worker. I think my logic is correct the code is wrong.
here's the methods, there is three ones:

[fullcode](http://pastebin.com/zXNrLFdY)

```
 bool piggybank::isLessthan(piggybank p2)
  {

if(printPiggyBankValue() < p2.printPiggyBankValue())
    return true;
else
    return false;

 }

bool piggybank::isGreaterthan(piggybank p2)

{
if(printPiggyBankValue() > p2.printPiggyBankValue())
    return true;
else
    return false;
}


piggybank piggybank::sumPiggyBanks(piggybank p2)
{
return PiggyBank(penny_num+p2.penny_num, nickel_num+p2.nickel_num, dime_num+p2.dime_num, quarter_num+p2.quarter_num);
}

void piggybank::printPiggyBankValue()
{
    double sum = 0;
    sum = (penny_num * penny) + ( nickel_num * nickel) + (dime_num * dime) + (quarter_num * quarter);
    cout << "$" << sum;
}
```

Comment: The logic of the code you've posted in this question is fine.  Although someone will eventually point out to you that your `if (x) return true; else return false;` is the same as `return x;`

Comment: You are comparing the (cout) strings? try getting the value (double)

Comment: The problem is that there is an error in the compiler, it says "error invalid operands to binary expression ('void' and 'void') "

Comment: Does the `printPiggyBankValue()` return a value?  You need a function that returns a value if you want to compare their results.

Comment: What is PiggyBank in piggybank::sumPiggyBanks?

Comment: why not use `operator>` (and `<`, `+`)?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you are using those functions in your comparison methods.
You should compare the data members directly:

```
class piggyBank
{
  public:
  bool operator<(const piggybank& p)
  {
    unsigned int this_sum = penny_num
        + nickel_num * 5;
        + dime_num * 10;
        + quarter_num * 25;
     unsigned int p_sum = p.penny_num
        + p.nickel_num * 5;
        + p.dime_num * 10;
        + p.quarter_num * 25;
    return this_sum < p_sum;
  }
};
```

In the above example, I summed up the currency in units of pennies, for *this* and the other object *p*.
I then compare the sums (or totals) and return that result.

Also, by naming the method `operator<` I can use the `<` to compare instances. :-)
No need to call "isLessThan".